# Saving a celery task (for re-running) in database

Tags: django, celery, celery-task

Our workflow is currently built around an old version of celery, so bear in mind things are already not optimal. We need to run a task and save a record of that task run in the database. If that task fails or hangs (it happens often), we want to re run, exactly as it was run the first time. This shouldn't happen automatically though. It needs to be triggered manually depending on the nature of the failure and the result needs to be logged in the DB to make that decision (via a front end).

How can we save a complete record of a task in the DB so that a subsequent process can grab the record and run a new identical task? The current implementation saves the path of the `@task` decorated function in the DB as part of a `TaskInfo` model. When the task needs to be rerun, we have a `get_task()` method on the `TaskInfo` model that gets the path from the DB, imports it using `getattr`, and another `rerun()` method that runs the task again with `*args, **kwargs` (also saved in the DB).

Like so (these are methods on the `TaskInfo` model instance):

```
def get_task(self):
    """Returns the task's decorated function, which can be delayed."""
    module_name, object_name = self.path.rsplit('.', 1)
    module = import_module(module_name)
    task = getattr(module, object_name)
    if inspect.isclass(task):
        task = task()
    # task = current_app.tasks[self.path]
    return task

 def rerun(self):
    """Re-run the task, and replace this one.

    - A new task is scheduled to run.
    - The new task's TaskInfo has the same parent as this TaskInfo.
    - This TaskInfo is deleted.
    """
    args, kwargs = self.get_arguments()
    celery_task = self.get_task()
    celery_task.delay(*args, **kwargs)
    defaults = {
        'path': self.path,
        'status': Status.PENDING,
        'timestamp': timezone.now(),
        'args': args,
        'kwargs': kwargs,
        'parent': self.parent,
    }
    TaskInfo.objects.update_or_create(task_id=celery_task.id, defaults=defaults)
    self.delete()
```

There must be a cleaner solution for saving a task in the DB to rerun later, right?

Comment: What is your result back-end set to? If your result-backend is a DB then the result, failure or not, will be written to the DB

Comment: Heh... `celery.backends.base.DisabledBackend`, so I guess the default, no result back-end. My guess is the original maintainer wanted to write some custom code for re running tasks and/or didn't know about storing results with the back end. Does the result backend contain enough information to re run a task after it finishes?

Comment: By default, result_backend simply recorded the task result, traceback, status and etc., so there is not enough info to rerun the task as it lacks the args and kwargs.

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of Celery (4.4.0) included a param `extended_result`. You can set it to True, then the table (it is named `celery_taskmeta` by default) in the `Result Backend Database` will store the `args and kwargs` of the task.

Here is a demo:

```
app = Celery('test_result_backend')

app.conf.update(
    broker_url='redis://localhost:6379/10',
    result_backend='db+mysql://root:passwd@localhost/celery_toys',
    result_extended=True
)


@app.task(bind=True, name='add')
def add(self, x, y): 
    self.request.task_name = 'add'  # For saving the task name.
    time.sleep(5)
    return x + y
```

With the task info recorded in MySQL, you are able to re-run your task easily.

Comment: You do not need any extended results for this. Args and kwargs are stored anyway.

Comment: yes, I see, I mean in this way, it can avoid writing any more logic for storing task meta into database.